# Check if JSON object null in JWT Authentication for WP REST API

Tags: json, swift, jwt

I am using the "[JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/)" plug-in to login in my wordpress in iOS.

When the access credentials are correct I get the response from the server:

```
{
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbG...",
    "user_email": "test@myhost.com",
    "user_id": 1
}
```

If the data is incorrect, I get the answer from the server:

```
{
    "code": "[jwt_auth] incorrect_password",
    "message": "<strong>ERROR</strong>: Incorrect password",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }
}
```

As I do to check, for example when the data is correct there is no 'code' and if the data is correct there is no 'token'

I tried like, but it does not work

```
let jsonObject = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

if jsonObject["token"] == nil {
    print("error password")
} else {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all use `Decodable`.

Create `Response` as enum with cases `success` and `failure` and associated types `TokenData` and `ErrorData`

```
enum Response : Decodable {

    case success(TokenData)
    case failure(ErrorData)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            self = try .success(container.decode(TokenData.self))
        } catch DecodingError.keyNotFound {
            self = try .failure(container.decode(ErrorData.self))
        }
    }
}

struct TokenData : Decodable {
    let token, userEmail : String
    let userId : Int
}

struct ErrorData : Decodable {
    let code, message : String
}
```

---

```
let jsonSuccessString = """
{
"token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbG...",
"user_email": "test@myhost.com",
"user_id": 1
}
"""

let jsonFailureString = """
{
"code": "[jwt_auth] incorrect_password",
"message": "<strong>ERROR</strong>: Incorrect password",
"data": {
"status": 403
}
}
"""
```

Decode the JSON and switch on the result, the example decodes both strings for demonstration

```
let successdata = Data(jsonSuccessString.utf8)
let failuredata = Data(jsonFailureString.utf8)

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

    let result1 = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: successdata)
    switch result1 {
        case .success(let tokenData) : print(tokenData) // TokenData(token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbG...", userEmail: "test@myhost.com", userId: 1)
        case .failure(let errorData) : print(errorData)
    }

    let result2 = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: failuredata)
    switch result2 {
        case .success(let tokenData) : print(tokenData)
        case .failure(let errorData) : print(errorData) // ErrorData(code: "[jwt_auth] incorrect_password", message: "<strong>ERROR</strong>: Incorrect password")
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```